# Unable to iterate through pl/sql cursor for loop

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cursor

Tbl_5 contains billing_centre name. I want to select data by joining other tables according to the billing center. So I created a cursor variable to hold the billing centers and want to iterate through it. But according to my query it does not iterate through all the billing_centre list and the query is also not executed. When I add 'for i in cur_bc' into the code 1, it does not show the sql query even in the exception part. Otherwise the exception part shows the query as shown in code 2.
Code 1:

```
    declare
    
    cursor cur_bc is select BILLING_CENTRE,cc from tbl_5 
    order by cc desc;
    c_rec cur_bc%rowtype;
    SQL_STR VARCHAR2(4000);
    
    begin
    
    open cur_bc;
    **for i in cur_bc**
    loop
    FETCH cur_bc into c_rec;  
    SQL_STR:='create table date_2
    tablespace R_TAB_TS
    storage (initial 1M next 1M)
    as 
    (select 
    t1.invoicing_co_id,
    t1.BILLING_CENTRE,
    t1.CUSTOMER_SEGMENT,
    t1.CREDIT_CLASS_ID,
    t1.CUSTOMER_TYPE_ID,
    t1.ACCOUNT_NUM,
    (select sum(p4.MON_BILL)
    from tbl_1 p4
    where p4.account_num = t1.account_num
    and substr(p4.en_bill_dtm,1,6) = ''202010'')a,
    (select sum(p3.MON_BILL)
    from tbl_1 p3
    where p3.account_num = t1.account_num
    and substr(p3.en_bill_dtm,1,6) = ''202011'')b,
    (select sum(p5.MON_BILL)
    from tbl_1 p5
    where p5.account_num = t1.account_num
    and substr(p5.en_bill_dtm,1,6) = ''202012'')c,
    (select sum(p1.MON_BILL)
    from tbl_1 p1
    where p1.account_num = t1.account_num
    and substr(p1.en_bill_dtm,1,6) = ''202101'')d,
    (select sum(p2.MON_BILL)
    from tbl_1 p2
    where p2.account_num = t1.account_num
    and substr(p2.en_bill_dtm,1,6) = ''202102'')e,
    (select sum(p6.MON_BILL)
    from tbl_1 p6
    where p6.account_num = t1.account_num
    and substr(p6.en_bill_dtm,1,6) = ''202103'')f,
    (select t2.AVG_BILL 
    from tbl_3 t2
    where t2.account_num = t1.account_num),
    (select t3.NO_OF_MONTHS 
    from tbl_3 t3
    where t3.account_num = t1.account_num),
    (select t22.AVG_3
    from tbl_3 t22
    where t22.account_num = t1.account_num),
    (select t33.NO_OF_MONTHS_3 
    from tbl_3 t33
    where t33.accaount_num = t1.account_num)
    from tbl_4 t1
    where t1.BILLING_CENTRE ='|| c_rec.billing_centre||';)';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQL_STR ;
    execute immediate 'commit;';
    end loop;
    
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('generated statement:'|| SQL_STR);
    
    end;
```

Code 2: Dynamic query obtained through the exception. Here, 'MD' is the value relevant to the largest 'cc' (Please refer the cursor variable in the declaration section.

```
generated statement:create table date_2
tablespace R_TAB_TS
storage (initial 1M next 1M)
as 
(select 
t1.invoicing_co_id,
t1.BILLING_CENTRE,
t1.CUSTOMER_SEGMENT,
t1.CREDIT_CLASS_ID,
t1.CUSTOMER_TYPE_ID,
t1.ACCOUNT_NUM,
(select sum(p4.MON_BILL)
from tbl_1 p4
where p4.account_num = t1.account_num
and substr(p4.en_bill_dtm,1,6) = '202010')a,
(select sum(p3.MON_BILL)
from tbl_1 p3
where p3.account_num = t1.account_num
and substr(p3.en_bill_dtm,1,6) = '202011')b,
(select sum(p5.MON_BILL)
from tbl_1 p5
where p5.account_num = t1.account_num
and substr(p5.en_bill_dtm,1,6) = '202012')c,
(select sum(p1.MON_BILL)
from tbl_1 p1
where p1.account_num = t1.account_num
and substr(p1.en_bill_dtm,1,6) = '202101')d,
(select sum(p2.MON_BILL)
from tbl_1 p2
where p2.account_num = t1.account_num
and substr(p2.en_bill_dtm,1,6) = '202102')e,
(select sum(p6.MON_BILL)
from tbl_1 p6
where p6.account_num = t1.account_num
and substr(p6.en_bill_dtm,1,6) = '202103')f,
(select t2.AVG_BILL 
from tbl_3 t2
where t2.account_num = t1.account_num),
(select t3.NO_OF_MONTHS 
from tbl_3 t3
where t3.account_num = t1.account_num),
(select t22.AVG_3
from tbl_3 t22
where t22.account_num = t1.account_num),
(select t33.NO_OF_MONTHS_3 
from tbl_3 t33
where t33.accaount_num = t1.account_num)
from tbl_4 t1
where t1.BILLING_CENTRE =MD;)
```

Can anyone identify the error in my query?

Comment: The generated SQL should start with `create table date_2` so I can't see how you got the SQL you posted beginning `(select t22.AVG_3`. Obviously you can't create the same table twice so that is one likely error if the loop has more than one iteration. If you want to loop through the cursor then why not use a cursor FOR loop? The open-loop-fetch-into approach seems unnecessarily complicated if you don't need the record outside the loop.

Comment: I have missed a part of the received dynamic query. I edited it.

Comment: One quick way to identify the error would be to remove your exception handler, as it currently hides all error details. My guess is *ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object.* How many times do you expect to create table date_2?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating two separate cursors when you probably only really want one.
Remove the explicit record and the `OPEN` and `FETCH` statements (and the already-missing `CLOSE` statement).

```
declare

cursor cur_bc is select BILLING_CENTRE,cc from tbl_5 
order by cc desc;
SQL_STR VARCHAR2(4000);

begin

--
-- a FOR loop with a cursor automatically creates the record
-- and automatically does the open/fetch/close
--
for cur_rec in cur_bc
loop
--
--
SQL_STR:='create table date_2
tablespace R_TAB_TS
storage (initial 1M next 1M)
as 
(select 
t1.invoicing_co_id,
t1.BILLING_CENTRE,
t1.CUSTOMER_SEGMENT,
t1.CREDIT_CLASS_ID,
t1.CUSTOMER_TYPE_ID,
t1.ACCOUNT_NUM,
(select sum(p4.MON_BILL)
from tbl_1 p4
where p4.account_num = t1.account_num
and substr(p4.en_bill_dtm,1,6) = ''202010'')a,
(select sum(p3.MON_BILL)
from tbl_1 p3
where p3.account_num = t1.account_num
and substr(p3.en_bill_dtm,1,6) = ''202011'')b,
(select sum(p5.MON_BILL)
from tbl_1 p5
where p5.account_num = t1.account_num
and substr(p5.en_bill_dtm,1,6) = ''202012'')c,
(select sum(p1.MON_BILL)
from tbl_1 p1
where p1.account_num = t1.account_num
and substr(p1.en_bill_dtm,1,6) = ''202101'')d,
(select sum(p2.MON_BILL)
from tbl_1 p2
where p2.account_num = t1.account_num
and substr(p2.en_bill_dtm,1,6) = ''202102'')e,
(select sum(p6.MON_BILL)
from tbl_1 p6
where p6.account_num = t1.account_num
and substr(p6.en_bill_dtm,1,6) = ''202103'')f,
(select t2.AVG_BILL 
from tbl_3 t2
where t2.account_num = t1.account_num),
(select t3.NO_OF_MONTHS 
from tbl_3 t3
where t3.account_num = t1.account_num),
(select t22.AVG_3
from tbl_3 t22
where t22.account_num = t1.account_num),
(select t33.NO_OF_MONTHS_3 
from tbl_3 t33
where t33.accaount_num = t1.account_num)
from tbl_4 t1
where t1.BILLING_CENTRE ='|| c_rec.billing_centre||';)';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQL_STR ;
execute immediate 'commit;';
end loop;

EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
dbms_output.put_line('generated statement:'|| SQL_STR);

end;
```

Note that the record is no longer needed in the `declare` section: the `cur_rec` cursor is implicitly defined by the loop syntax.
The record `cur_rec` will be valid within the scope of the loop and will have your values.

The "for my_rec in my_cur" syntax is very convenient because it performs the same as a `OPEN`, followed by `FETCH` and `FOUND`/`NOTFOUND` tests and then finally a `CLOSE`.